# Get smallest t items from an array of integers of size n

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of size n of unsorted integers and I would like to print the smallest t elements from it.

For example, if I have the following array:

```
int[] input = {5,6,2,5,7,8,9,1,22,64,3,4} 
int t = 5;
```

Then my result should be:

```
result = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Requested code:

```
Arrays.sort(input);

for(int i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
    System.out.println(input[i]);
}
```

Currently how I'm going it is I'm sorting the array using Arrays.sort(), and then iterating through the first t terms to print it. This solves the problem in O(nlgn). However, if I have a an array with a sufficiently large size (n > 1000) then it seems like bad practice to sort the whole thing to get t number of elements (assuming t is much smaller than n).

I was wondering if there is some other data structure in Java which can do it more efficiently? Maybe something that linearly probes the array and creates a smaller array of size t and fills it with the smallest t elements in the original array by utilizing some check?

I was looking into a Priority Queue or a MinHeap but I'm not sure if it solves the problem I'm having, which is to solve it in better than O(nlgn) time.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Just use a ring buffer.

Comment: Do my home work for me question?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: send it , i'll help you

Comment: Does the output have to be sorted?

Comment: I think you should investigate the min heap idea further.  If I remember correctly, building a min heap is O(n).  Subsequently, as you remove each minimum element, maintaining the min heap is O(log n).  So you have `t` times log(n) accesses plus O(n), which is less than O(n log n).

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I added in my code. Since its so straightforward I thought people would be able to get it without me pasting it in.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat It can be sorted in O(tlgt) time which is better than O(nlgn) so its still better.

Comment: @FlameDra people are able to get it , some people send their homework and try to get the code that they can't write it ...

Comment: this is not the true code , wrong answer for that input ...

Comment: maybe it was better to use Map ...